# Gradle don't sees my tasks when i tried register its

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

I have created DefaultTask inside my buildSrc

```
-buildSrc
   -src
     -main/java/work.FilePrefTask.kt
   -build.gradle.kts
```

FilePrefTask view

```
abstract class FilePrefTask: DefaultTask() {

    @TaskAction
    fun action(){
        println("Hello world")
    }
```

build.gradle.kts

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}

tasks.register<FilePrefTask>("prefTask",FilePrefTask::class){

}
    }
```

But when I try make async I get exceptions

```
 \buildSrc\build.gradle.kts:9:16: Unresolved reference: FilePrefTask
\buildSrc\build.gradle.kts:9:61: Passing value as a vararg is only allowed inside a parenthesized argument list
Script compilation errors:
```

I tried add import after had moved in other packet my DefaultTask but without success

And nothing else. What i did incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`buildSrc/build.gradle.kts` is the build script of your custom task or script templates under `buildSrc/src`. You should apply the task in `app/build.gradle.kts` instead.